# How to Save profile account in database when I click the save button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to save profile account into databae.?

my features in saving account in database are ff:

FirstName:
LastName:
Address:
City:
Country:
Age:
Sex:
Status:
Nationality:
Occupation:
Email Address:
Password:

```
  Save Button
```

Note:
Country-I used country as the dropdownlist where in all countries are listed.so the user will just select which
        country he/she has.
Sex-is also a dropdown list.the user will have to select the value only male or female
status - is also a dropdownlist.the user select the value only single,married,widowed and separate.

anyone can give me this codes using asp.net and c#..Thank you for paying this attention.I highly appreciate your effort..It helps a lot on me..

this is my code.please check my code..there is a runtime error..

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

string conn = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);

```
    string First = TextBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Last = TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Address = TextBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string City = TextBox4.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Country =DropDownList1;
    string Age = TextBox5.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Sex = DropDownList2;
    string Status = DropDownList3;
    string Nationality = TextBox6.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Occupation = TextBox7.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Email = TextBox8.Text.Replace("'", "''");
    string Pass = TextBox9.Text.Replace("'", "''");

    connection.Open();
    string sql = "INSERT INTO [ProfileTbl]([FirstName],[LastName],[Address],[City],[Country],[Age],[Sex],[Status],[Nationality],[Occupation],[EmailAddress],[Password]) Values('" + First + "','" + Last + "','" + Address + "','" + City + "','" + Country + "','" + Age + "','"+ Sex +"','"+ Status +"','"+ Nationality +"','"+ Occupation +"','"+ Email +"','"+ Pass+"')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    TextBox3.Text = "";
    TextBox4.Text = "";
    TextBox5.Text = "";
    TextBox6.Text = "";
    TextBox7.Text = "";
    TextBox8.Text = "";
    TextBox9.Text = "";
    DropDownList1 = "";
    DropDownList2 = "";
    DropDownList3 = "";
    Response.Redirect("~/Default4.aspx");

}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you experiencing?  This question will likely be closed because you not made an effort to do this yourself first.

Comment: i try this..but the thing is i don't know how to codes all the dropdownlist and save into database..

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? And please format your question's code snippets. While it might look correct in the editor the final outcome is wrong. I would edit your post, but I have no idea what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @user2280101, based on your comment, you have 2 questions: 1) how to make a DropDownList hold values (like PKs) for use in the database, and 2) how to store/retrieve data from a database. These are completely different and vague in your situation.

Comment: yes correct..anyway i will format my question code..

Comment: @user2280101, correct to what? Are you trying to ask 2 questions at once?

Comment: no i mean ur correct.because 2 questions vague in my situation..i dont know how to store the dropdownlist value into database..can you help me? if you have an idea pls help me..

Comment: this is my code.please check my code..there is a runtime error..

Comment: This code is simply horrible, sorry. What is this??? `DropDownList1 = ""`. Furthermore, if you get an exception, maybe you should post what error message do you get?

Comment: Seriously, I don't believe you even get pass the compiler! For instance this is an utter nonsense `string Sex = DropDownList2;` Not mentioning that doubling of single quotes, what are you trying to achieve by that? Prevent SQL injection? Hopefully not... Get a book and start learning the basics, we can't help you here.

Comment: Error 31 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' to 'string'

Error 34 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error 31  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' to 'string' Error    34 Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'

Exactly as I've said in the comments. You can't use dropdownlists like this.
DropDownList has a property for accessing the currently selected value

```
string selectedItemValue = dropDownListInstance.SelectedValue;
```

Or maybe:

```
string selectedItemValue = dropDownListInstance.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer..i appreciate it..thats what only i want.im just also a beginer that is why i reffer to forum because i think someone can help me..